# Bibliography in wrong order on Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies

I've got a .bib file which I have the references in the order that they appear in the document.

```
@article{pinelle2003task,
  title={Task analysis for groupware usability evaluation: Modeling shared-workspace tasks with the mechanics of collaboration},
  author={Pinelle, David and Gutwin, Carl and Greenberg, Saul},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Computer-Human Interaction (TOCHI)},
  volume={10},
  number={4},
  pages={281--311},
  year={2003},
  publisher={ACM}
}

@article{sefelin2003paper,
  title={Paper prototyping-what is it good for?: a comparison of paper-and computer-based low-fidelity prototyping},
  author={Sefelin, Reinhard and Tscheligi, Manfred and Giller, Verena},
  booktitle={CHI'03 extended abstracts on Human factors in computing systems},
  pages={778--779},
  year={2003},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{virzi1996usability,
  title={Usability problem identification using both low-and high-fidelity prototypes},
  author={Virzi, Robert A and Sokolov, Jeffrey L and Karis, Demetrios},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
  pages={236--243},
  year={1996},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{khalifa1997computer,
  title={Computer-assisted evaluation of interface designs},
  author={Khalifa, Mohamed},
  journal={ACM SIGMIS Database},
  volume={29},
  number={1},
  pages={66--81},
  year={1997},
  publisher={ACM}
}

@article{borsci2013reviewing,
  title={Reviewing and extending the five-user assumption: A grounded procedure for interaction evaluation},
  author={Borsci, Simone and Macredie, Robert D and Barnett, Julie and Martin, Jennifer and Kuljis, Jasna and Young, Terry},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Computer-Human Interaction (TOCHI)},
  volume={20},
  number={5},
  pages={29},
  year={2013},
  publisher={ACM}
}

@article{lewis2000overestimation,
  title={Overestimation of p in problem discovery usability studies: How serious is the problem},
  author={Lewis, James R},
  year={2000},
  institution={Tech. Rep}
}

@article{turner2006determining,
  title={Determining usability test sample size},
  author={Turner, Carl W and Lewis, James R and Nielsen, Jakob},
  journal={International encyclopedia of ergonomics and human factors},
  volume={3},
  pages={3084--3088},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}
```

In the document I am using `\cite{}` to reference them and I am doing so in the order that they appear in the .bib. However, the bibliography at the end of the document and the corresponding number in the document appear to be in a a totally random order.

```
[1] S. Borsci, R. D. Macredie, J. Barnett, J. Martin,
J. Kuljis, and T. Young. Reviewing and extending the
five-user assumption: A grounded procedure for
interaction evaluation. ACM Transactions on
Computer-Human Interaction (TOCHI), 20(5):29, 2013.
[2] M. Khalifa. Computer-assisted evaluation of interface
designs. ACM SIGMIS Database, 29(1):66–81, 1997.
[3] J. R. Lewis. Overestimation of p in problem discovery
usability studies: How serious is the problem. 2000.
[4] D. Pinelle, C. Gutwin, and S. Greenberg. Task analysis
for groupware usability evaluation: Modeling
shared-workspace tasks with the mechanics of
collaboration. ACM Transactions on Computer-Human
Interaction (TOCHI), 10(4):281–311, 2003.
[5] R. Sefelin, M. Tscheligi, and V. Giller. Paper
prototyping-what is it good for?: a comparison of
paper-and computer-based low-fidelity prototyping.
pages 778–779, 2003.
[6] C. W. Turner, J. R. Lewis, and J. Nielsen. Determining
usability test sample size. International encyclopedia of
ergonomics and human factors, 3:3084–3088, 2006.
[7] R. A. Virzi, J. L. Sokolov, and D. Karis. Usability
problem identification using both low-and high-fidelity
prototypes. pages 236–243, 1996.
```

How do I make it so that the place of the reference in the .bib file corresponds to it's place in the bibliography.

Comment: We would need to see a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). The order in the bibliography very much depends on the bibliography styles.

Comment: bibtex never uses the order in the bib file, the standard orders are order of citation in the document or alphabetical order of authors

Comment: i don't know of any tool that can re-order a `.bib` file to be in the same order as the appearance of the references in a paper.  (there are some tools, at least for `bibtex`, that can order alphabetically by author.)  such an arrangement is usually expected to be the responsibility of the author.

Comment: many people will not download zip files from external sites, please make a small complete document and add it inline to your question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah just realised that it is alphabetical based on the author's surname. I don't know much about referencing and just assumed it was meant to go in order where [1] would always be the first reference to appear. Is that not the case?

Comment: no the ordering is specified by the bibliography style (which you have not shown in the question) the ordering in the bibtex file is intentionally not relevant as it's supposed to be a database of references, many people accumulate hundreds of references in their bibtex files used over multiple documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah okay, I am using `abbrv`. I changed it to `unsrt` and now it works as I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a bibliography style that specifies numbering in order of appearance in the document (order in the .bib file is never relevant) such as

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Comment: It works perfectly in my template